# Django auth confusion in templates

Tags: django, templates, authentication

Im playing about with the django auth library, and ive come across something i dont understand.

I have a master template `base.html` and inside this template i have the following code:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   Welcome {{user.username}}, <a href='/accounts/logout/'>Logout</a>
{% else %}
   Welcome Guest, Please <a href='/accounts/login/'>Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

This is repeated on every page, in the header. After ive logged in however, on all but the login page itself, it shows the `welcome guest...` string, as if there is no authenticated user.

Confusingly however, the auth library appears to be doing its job elsewhere, i cant access login protected functions, and i can after ive logged in etc.

Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-data-in-templates):

> Technically, these variables are only made available in the template context if you use `RequestContext` and your [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting contains `"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"`, which is default. For more, see the [RequestContext docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Answer (score 1):

Please provide code from the `views.py` which accesses this template. But if my guess is right, you might not be passing the `user` instance  to the template.

In the case of absence of a particular variable, Django Templates considers it as False.

You need to do it like this -

```
...
var  = RequestContext(request,'somevar':somevar})
return render_to_response('somehtml.html', var)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for "user" is not in your context. Generic views, like the standard login, already have a RequestContext instance passed.

You need to [create your own](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and then pass that instance of the dictionary when rendering the template. The generic views do this automatically.